# Can I call a non-const member function of a const object in C++?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following code:

```
Class Object{
    public:
      Object(int i):_val(i) {}
      void doNotChangeObject() { /*Doesn't change 'val'*/}
    private
      int _val;
};

int main{
   const Object obj(1);
   obj.doNotChangeObject();
   return 0;
}
```

Would this code produce a compilation error because I'm calling a non-const member function of a const object?

Comment: This would produce many compilation errors. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I call a non member function of a const object

You cannot call non member functions "on" an object. You can pass an object as an argument, though.

> Can I call a non const member function of a const object

No.

> Woud this code produce a compilation error?

Yes. You call a non-`const` member function on a `const` object.

Comment: Indeed I meant non-const (fixed now) Thanks!